# ggplot: stacked barplot in reverse order

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have data frame

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Frequency = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Prcentage = c(1, 
33, 58, 8, 2, 40, 53, 5), label = list("Insufficient", "Average", 
    "Good", "Excellent", "Insufficient", "Average", "Good", "Excellent"), 
    name = c("implementation", "implementation", "implementation", 
    "implementation", "energy", "energy", "energy", "energy")), .Names = c("Frequency", 
"Prcentage", "label", "name"), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

And with following code

```
# Get the levels for type in the required order
df$label = factor(df$label, levels = c("Unacceptable","Insufficient", "Average","Good","Excellent"))
df = arrange(df, name, desc(label))

# Format the labels and calculate their positions
df = ddply(df, .(name), transform, pos = (cumsum(Prcentage) - 0.5 * Prcentage))
df$label1 = paste0(sprintf("%.0f", df$Prcentage), "%")


# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(name), y = Prcentage, fill = label, order=desc(label))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(y = pos, label = label1), size = 4) +  theme_classic() + 
  scale_y_continuous(position = "top",expand = c(0, 0),breaks = seq(min(0), max(0,102), by = 10),limits = c(0,102),labels = dollar_format(suffix = "%", prefix = "")) + 
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("") + ylab("") + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom",legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ff0000","#fff68f","#b2b2b2","#1baf05","#006080"),drop = FALSE)
```

I produce the following plot

[image]

But now I am struggling to get the bars in reverse order. **Sm my output** should be reverse stacked with the right values in bars (e.g. 1% yellow should be positioned first in the left side of the plot, then follows 33%, then 56% and far right 8%). I've already tried to do this with adding

```
+ geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) (after geom_bar)
```

Which produced this

[image]

But this in not correct as values in bars are not correct.

I've also looked here

[How to control ordering of stacked bar chart using identity on ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2)

[Reverse fill order for histogram bars in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613950/reverse-fill-order-for-histogram-bars-in-ggplot2)

[Order Stacked Bar Graph in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186436/order-stacked-bar-graph-in-ggplot)

[Reverse fill order for histogram bars in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613950/reverse-fill-order-for-histogram-bars-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The position of the labels is directly set by the `pos` value, you need to reverse that f you reverse the stack order:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(name))) +
  geom_col(aes(y = Prcentage, fill = label), 
           position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE),
           width = .5) +
  # Set the position to its complementary
  geom_text(aes(y = 100 - pos, label = label1)) +

  # Rest of theme
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "top", 
                     expand = c(0, 0),
                     breaks = seq(min(0), max(0,102), by = 10),
                     limits = c(0,102),
                     labels = dollar_format(suffix = "%", prefix = "")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ff0000","#fff68f","#b2b2b2","#1baf05","#006080"), drop = FALSE) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",legend.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Comment: One question: Today I tried running your code from different computer (R version 3.2.2) and a keep getting error: `Error: could not find function "geom_col"`. Any Idea?

Comment: I think `geom_col` has been introduced recently. If using a older version of `ggplot2` and can't upgrade `geom_bar(..., stat='identity')` is equivalent

Comment: Thx, I've sold the problem, just manually updated `ggplot` package. Now `geom_col` works.

Comment: @Miha Also note that there are now options to stack text in ggplot2 rather than need to make a `pos` variable.  Example: `geom_text(aes(y = Prcentage, label = label1), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE, vjust = .5))`