# R: Histogram Stacking by Amount

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a ggplot graphic with a histogram with binwidth = 1.
It is made with this code:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Rating)) + coord_fixed() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()
  ) +
geom_histogram(aes(fill=partei), binwidth = 1) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#a1a1a1","#D0B100","#FF8B07","#5675D6","#A3DD57","#CE2929","#428953"))
```

[image: ggplot]

I would like the items to be ordered by amount. For example, the blue squares should be at the bottom below the orange columns, because there is only one blue square and many orange ones. Also, it would be nice if the light green square was above the red area. Any idea how the stacking can be ordered according to the amount

This is the data:

```
    p_id    Rating partei
 1:  172 -5.628094     SP
 2:  305 -5.489508     SP
 3:  321  9.775742    SVP
 4:  341 -9.540089     SP
 5:  466 -3.875883     SP
 6:  477 -2.474366     SP
 7:  525 -3.789094     SP
 8:  540  1.362994    CVP
 9:  801  1.255944    FDP
10:  823 -2.626939     SP
11:  825  7.280470    SVP
12: 1106  1.882722    CVP
13: 1141  3.733562    FDP
14: 1148 -5.943324     SP
15: 1150 -6.212764     SP
16: 1153  3.077083    FDP
17: 1162  5.936169    SVP
18: 1267 -3.543711     SP
19: 3831  1.932549    CVP
20: 3871  1.315812    CVP
21: 3879  1.608675    FDP
22: 3891 -1.629615     SP
23: 3914 -2.938615    GPS
24: 3915  2.416889    CVP
25: 3916 -5.675579     SP
26: 3918  1.217664    BDP
27: 3920  1.223370    CVP
28: 3921  1.871879    CVP
29: 4055  1.961057    CVP
30: 4062  3.496568    FDP
31: 4064  3.886054    FDP
32: 4068  6.057008    SVP
33: 4075  4.040331    FDP
34: 4078  4.152061    FDP
35: 4088  1.954443    CVP
36: 4112  5.090271      -
37: 4139  4.025476    FDP
38: 4145  7.085134    SVP
39: 4151  3.307654    FDP
40: 4152  3.911100    FDP
41: 4153  1.805892    CVP
42: 4204  2.402280    CVP
43: 4205  1.267867    CVP
44: 4206  1.160906    CVP
45: 4207  2.871954    FDP
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186436/order-stacked-bar-graph-in-ggplot

Comment: hm, i want it to be ordered within the stack, no reorder on the x-axis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, it can be done easily by modifying levels order.
I needed to specific each combination of level and color to save the same colors.

If you want more flexibily, the easiest might be to create a new data.frame with more columns.
You can also keep the old legend by modifying the actual one in `scale_fill`
[image]

```
data$partei <- factor(data$partei, levels=c("-", "FDP", "BDP", "CVP", "SP", "SVP", "GPS"))

ggplot(data, aes(x = Rating)) + coord_fixed() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()
  ) +
geom_histogram(aes(fill=partei), binwidth = 1) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c( "-" = "#a1a1a1","BDP" = "#D0B100", "CVP" = "#FF8B07", "FDP" = "#5675D6", "GPS" = "#A3DD57", "SP" = "#CE2929", "SVP" = "#428953"))
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much! great solution! (even though it would be nice if it was a general ggplot option to sort by amount...)