# R/ggplot2 - sort stacked barplot bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot I've dynamically created from a data.frame that looks like this:

```
slug      provider     n
id1       facebook     1
id2       twitter      1
id2       facebook     1
id3       email        1
...        ...         ...
```

Here is a gist with some toy data: https://gist.github.com/gaiusjaugustus/b8b0b61907fdb952ce481c2c7c05f76c

And created a plot with the following code.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=slug, y=n, fill=provider)) + geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format())
```

[image: Stacked Bar plot]

As you can see above, there are a lot of categories.  What I'd like to do is somehow SORT the x-axis `slugs` so that we can see trends. Here are a few examples:
[image: Latino populations ancestry]

See how this is organized so that you can really see trends well?  Any help with getting this to work with ggplot2 would be great.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186436/order-stacked-bar-graph-in-ggplot

Comment: That worked.  A full day of searching SO, and I couldn't find it.  Thanks.