# Multiple barplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8186560) example I try to plot the following

Dataset is the following:

```
df <- structure(list(year = 2002:2005, work = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), confid = c(8L, 
5L, 0L, 6L), jrs = c(0L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("year", "work", 
"confid", "jrs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

The code in order to plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
md <- melt(df, id=(c("year")))
temp.plot<-ggplot(data=md, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable) ) + 
    geom_bar()+ opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90)) + 
    opts(title = "Score Distribtion")
```

And the error I receive:

```
Error: could not find function "opts"
```

I tried to remove the opts() from graph but again I receive the same error.

What could it be the problem?

Comment: This is for an old version of ggplot. `opts` has been replaced by `theme`. Use `labs` or `ggtitle` to get the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An updated version of your code using `theme` in substitution of `opts`:

```
df <- structure(list(year = 2002:2005, work = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), confid = c(8L, 
5L, 0L, 6L), jrs = c(0L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("year", "work", 
"confid", "jrs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
md <- melt(df, id=(c("year")))
temp.plot <- ggplot(data=md, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable) ) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity")+ 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))+ 
    ggtitle("Score Distribtion")

temp.plot
```

[image]