# Show the table of values under the bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I ask this without find something to try, because I didn't find something same. I apologize for this.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44356062/8088458) bar plot:

```
df <- structure(list(year = 2002:2005, work = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), confid = c(8L, 
5L, 0L, 6L), jrs = c(0L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("year", "work", 
"confid", "jrs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
md <- melt(df, id=(c("year")))
temp.plot <- ggplot(data=md, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable) ) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity")+ 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))+ 
    ggtitle("Score Distribtion")

temp.plot
```

I would like to ask if is there any simple way using ggplot2 to have the value under every year as it is in barplot for every variable.
Here a dummy example output:
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It might be better to plot the counts within each bar. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_classic())

ggplot(data=md, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  ggtitle("Score Distribution") +
  geom_text(aes(label=value), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="white") +
  labs(fill="")
```

[image]

If you still want a table beneath the plot, I don't know of a simple way, but you can create a separate `tableGrob` for the table, extract the legend as a separate grob (graphical object), then lay out each part separately. Laying out the various parts requires some tweaking by hand, although someone who understands grid graphics better than I do might be able to automate that. Here's an example:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

# Function to extract legend
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/13650878/496488
g_legend <- function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}

p = ggplot(data=md, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable) ) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+ 
  #theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, hjust=0.5))+ 
  ggtitle("Score Distribution") +
  labs(fill="")

# Extract the legend as a separate grob
leg = g_legend(p)

# Create a table grob
tab = t(df)
tab = tableGrob(tab, rows=NULL)
tab$widths <- unit(rep(1/ncol(tab), ncol(tab)), "npc")

# Lay out plot, legend, and table grob
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(nullGrob(), 
                         p + guides(fill=FALSE) + 
                           theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                                 axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                                 axis.ticks.x=element_blank()),
                         widths=c(1,8)), 
             arrangeGrob(arrangeGrob(nullGrob(),leg,heights=c(1,10)),
                         tab, nullGrob(), widths=c(6,20,1)),
             heights=c(4,1))
```

[image]